# How to transfer a project from user to a group in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I want to move a project under my username/ownership to a group whose owner is a different user. Something like https://gitlab/user/project to https://gitlab/group/project

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14):

You can do this in the left-hand sidebar, under `Settings` -> `General` -> `Transfer project`.  You will need manage rights to that group that you are transferring to though.

> - Be careful. Changing the project's namespace can have unintended side    effects.
> - You can only transfer the project to namespaces you manage.
> - You will need to update your local repositories to point to the new    location.
> - Project visibility level will be changed to match namespace rules    when transferring to a group.

Comment: Do I need to have master role for the group to which I am transferring?

Comment: You should only need access to create projects within that group

Comment: I do have the access to create projects in that group. Yet I don't get any options to transfer the project. Found a workaround though, exporting and importing. Commits and branches were retained too.